# Modify cell on didSelectRowAtIndexPath in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have 2 views on a table view cell view1 and view2 and what i want to do is when i tap on a cell i want that view1 to be hidden and view2 to be displayed (at the beginning view1 was displayed and view2 was hidden), I used tags for view view1  = 102 and view2 = 103, for some reason I which i can not figure, the view1 is hidden but the view2 is not displayed.

here is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    UIView * view1 = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
    UIView * view2 = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:103];

    [view1 setHidden:YES];
    [view2 setHidden:NO];


    NSLog(@"View 2 is : %hhd",view2.hidden);


}
```

storyBoard
[image]

simulator

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

instead of

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

use

```
cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Because `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: forIndexPath:` will return a currently unused table cell that is currently not visible.